# In SQL how can i show the sales of city's with 0 when they dont have sales in a year. I have city table and transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the total sales of each city for each year, but my table doesn't have sales for cities in some years and we don't see that information as well.

Now I want to prepare a result set saying the sales of all city's in year and display the cities which don't have sales in a year with value 0

City table

| CityKey | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NYC |
| 2 | Dallas |
| 3 | San Francisco |

Transaction table

| City | Total sales | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 100 | 2019 |
| Dallas | 50 | 2019 |
| San Francisco | 100 | 2019 |
| NYC | 222 | 2020 |

Output - transactions per city:

| City | Total sales | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 100 | 2019 |
| Dallas | 50 | 2019 |
| San Francisco | 100 | 2019 |
| NYC | 222 | 2020 |
| Dallas | 0 | 2020 |
| San Francisco | 0 | 2020 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the rows, then `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select c.city, y.year, coalesce(t.total_sales, 0)
from cities c cross join
     (select distinct year from transactions) y left join
     transactions t
     on t.city = c.city and t.year = y.year;
```

Comment: this code doesnt help and lot of performance issues. I have City table,Year tabel and transaction tables separately

Comment: @user15488631 . . . Then just use the year table instead of `y`.  You don't mention it in your question.